# How do i connect these Ip cameras

Tags: camera

I have zoneminder in my RPI 2 and i would like to know how to connect these 2 cameras, please.
Hikvision DS-2CE56C0T-IRF 
Hikvision DS-2CE16C0T-IRPF 2.8

they come at really nice price and i would like to ask what is the way to connect them to the RPI, either with and without zoneminder.

Comment: I feel the need to point out that neither of those seem to be I *P* cameras, they are IR cameras. An IP camera is a camera that is network-accessible in some way, an IR camera is one that has an option to see IR light (usually "night vision").

Answer (score 0):

To me they look like analogue cameras. So you will have to get an [USB video grabber](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-Black-USB-2-0-Video-Capture-Card-Converter-PC-Adapter-TV-Audio-DVD-DVR/32810270722.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.8.6b365b44uNTy58&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10320_10152_10321_10065_10151_10344_10068_10342_10547_10343_10322_10340_10548_10341_10193_10696_10194_10084_10083_10618_10304_10307_10302_10180_10313_10059_10184_10682_10534_10681_10683_100031_10319_10103_10624_10680_10623_443_10622_10186_10621_10620,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=5d15414d-70c0-4141-9351-bc15060c5e70-1&algo_pvid=5d15414d-70c0-4141-9351-bc15060c5e70&transAbTest=ae803_5&priceBeautifyAB=0) and set it up with UV4L.

Comment: Today i paid a visit to a shop and i have seen the camera it is analogue indeed. The usb device you suggested it does not seem to have the appropriate connectors to the cameras i mentioned? Am i wrong? is there any way to find the appropriate connection? also how many of these usb devices can i connect to the RPI?

Comment: The plugs may differ but the signal CVBS is the right one. But I don't know where you can get an adapter for those cameras. I'd suggest you try to find ones with the right plug.